# Flutter textformfield auto de-focus

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

This is the function I'm using to get a form displayed on my screen.

```
Form getNewLoanForm() {
return new Form(
  child: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Loan name'),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Enter name';
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
        onSaved: (value) => _loanName = value,
      ),
      new Container(height: 16.0),
      new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text(
          'ADD',
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
        ),
        onPressed: addNewLoan,
        color: Colors.blue,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Everything works fine up unit now. The problem starts when I add

```
final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

I declare this varial in class level. and use it in form.

```
return new Form(
  key: formKey,
```

Like this and now the TextFormField starts to behave weirdly. Now if I select the text field it deselects itself.

Now keep in mind that this doesn't happen if I make this page my root page. But I'm pushing this page from my root page. If I make this page my root page the problem doesn't occur there.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Okay I'm putting my whole class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewLoan extends StatelessWidget {
   String _loanName;
   String _dateCreated;
   final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

   void addNewLoan() {}

   Form getNewLoanForm(BuildContext context) {
       final dateFormat = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       return new Form(
       // key: formKey,
       child: new Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
       children: <Widget>[
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Loan name'),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Enter name';
          } else {
            _loanName = value;
            return null;
          }
        },
      ),
      new Container(height: 16.0),
      DateTimePickerFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Date'),
        format: dateFormat,
        dateOnly: true,
        onChanged: (date) {
          print('Selected date ${date.toString()}');
          Scaffold
              .of(context)
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$date')));
        },
      ),
      new Container(height: 16.0),
      new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text(
          'ADD',
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
        ),
        onPressed: addNewLoan,
        color: Colors.blue,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('New Loan'),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: getNewLoanForm(context),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

My Root page

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase/new_loan.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'current_balance_page.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({this.auth, this.onSignOut});
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

FirebaseApp app;
Future<FirebaseApp> firebaseApp() async {
  final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'hisab-442a2',
    options: Platform.isIOS
        ? const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '1:18726312:ios:1b7829f2ac180d28',
            gcmSenderID: '75461431231231291692',
            databaseURL: 'https://hisab-44s2a2.firebaseio.com',
          )
        : const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '1:297855924061:android:669871c998cc21bd',
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyD_shO5mfO9lhy2TVWhfo1VUmARKlG4suk',
            databaseURL: 'https://hisab-442a2.firebaseio.com',
          ),
  );
  return app;
}

enum Balancestatus { checking, found, noBalance }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Balancestatus status = Balancestatus.checking;
  DatabaseReference _databaseRef;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDatabaseRef();
  }

  void getDatabaseRef() async {
    app = await firebaseApp();
    final FirebaseDatabase database = new FirebaseDatabase(app: app);
    _databaseRef = database.reference();
    _databaseRef.child('ccurrent_balance').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Current balance ${snapshot.value}');
      int balance = snapshot.value;
      setState(() {
        if (balance == null || balance == 0) {
          status = Balancestatus.noBalance;
        } else {
          status = Balancestatus.found;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  Future _signOut() async {
    try {
      await widget.auth.singOut();
      widget.onSignOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error signing out: $e');
    }
  }

  void balanceSet() {
    setState(() {
      status = Balancestatus.checking;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (status) {
      case Balancestatus.checking:
        return new WelcomePage(onSignOut: _signOut);
      case Balancestatus.found:
      // return new NewLoan();
        return new LoanList(onSignOut: _signOut);
      case Balancestatus.noBalance:
        return CurrentBalancePage(
          databaseRef: _databaseRef,
          balanceSet: balanceSet,
        );
      default:
        return new WelcomePage(onSignOut: _signOut);
    }
  }
}

class LoanList extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;

  LoanList({this.onSignOut});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Loans'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text(
              'Logout',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: onSignOut,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(
            'New Loan',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
          ),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewLoan()));
          },
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addNewLoan() {
    print('Add new Loan');
  }
}

class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;

  WelcomePage({this.onSignOut});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Welcome'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text(
              'Logout',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: onSignOut,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(
            'Checking',
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you declare this ? final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();     could you put all of your stateful class

Comment: @diegoveloper i have added my entire class in question.

Comment: I tested and It's working fine, how are you calling NewLoan widget?

Comment: onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
            );
          },

Comment: where did you call NewLoan ?

Comment: I'll share the entire project with you tonight. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Just put the widget that call that loan widget, because I run your Loan class using the form key and it's working fine. Maybe you have a parent stateful widget which is rebuilding the tree.

Comment: @diegoveloper I have added my Root page now